# Build Error. Failed to fetch http://deb.debian.org/debian/dists/jessie-updates/main/binary-amd64/Packages

Tags: docker, build, continuous-integration, continuous-deployment, gitlab-ci-runner

Build Errors unable to find jq.

Err http://deb.debian.org jessie/main amd64 Packages
  404  Not Found
Err http://deb.debian.org jessie-updates/main amd64 Packages
  404  Not Found
Fetched 723 kB in 2s (357 kB/s)
W: Failed to fetch http://deb.debian.org/debian/dists/jessie/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://deb.debian.org/debian/dists/jessie-updates/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
$ apt-get install jq
Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
E: Unable to locate package jq
ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1

Comment: Hey did . you fix this?

Answer (score 9):

@codinghaus mentioned in another thread:

> This is due to the fact that
>   as Wheezy and Jessie have been integrated into the archive.debian.org structure recently, we are now removing all of Wheezy and all non-LTS architectures of Jessie from the mirror network starting today.

A solution (according to https://github.com/debuerreotype/docker-debian-artifacts/issues/66#issuecomment-476616579) is to add the following command into your Dockerfile before calling any apt-get update when using debian:jessie.

```
RUN sed -i '/jessie-updates/d' /etc/apt/sources.list  # Now archived
```

This will remove the jessie-updates repository (which now causes the 404) from sources.list.

```
FROM debian:jessie
RUN sed -i '/jessie-updates/d' /etc/apt/sources.list  # Now archived
RUN apt-get update
CMD /bin/sh
```

Answer (score 4):

Just place this line before your `apt-get` commands in your Dockerfile:

```
RUN echo "deb http://deb.debian.org/debian jessie main" > /etc/apt/sources.list
```

Debian removed some url for old packages which is causing this issue. The line fixes the repository to refer to.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem today. I believe yours is related to Jessie being removed from Debian (see: https://twitter.com/debian/status/1109080168318926851?s=12).

I upgraded php in Dockerfile to `php:7.1.27-apache-stretch` and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe, the third party import that you are doing is not able to refer to the debian jessie, so changing ftp.debian.org to http://ftp.us.debian.org might make it work. If you are not referring to this directly, try upgrading or downgrading the imported versions, if removing them is not the option.

In my case, i was using:

```
FROM docker.***.com/node:10
```

downgrading the node from 10 to 8, kicked off the job successfully.