# A docker image based on "php:5.6.32-apache" fails to build when running "RUN apt-get update -y"

Tags: docker, dockerfile, debian-jessie

I want to build a docker image based on `php:5.6.32-apache`.

The content involved in this within my Dockerfile is:

```
FROM php:5.6.32-apache

....

RUN apt-get update -y
```

The console output from the built process is:

```
Step 6/10 : RUN apt-get update -y
 ---> Running in 8781a7a005ad
Get:1 http://security.debian.org jessie/updates InRelease [44.9 kB]
Ign http://deb.debian.org jessie InRelease
Get:2 http://deb.debian.org jessie-updates InRelease [7340 B]
Get:3 http://deb.debian.org jessie Release.gpg [2420 B]
Get:4 http://deb.debian.org jessie Release [148 kB]
Get:5 http://security.debian.org jessie/updates/main amd64 Packages [846 kB]
Get:6 http://deb.debian.org jessie/main amd64 Packages [9098 kB]
W: Failed to fetch http://deb.debian.org/debian/dists/jessie-updates/InRelease  Unable to find expected entry 'main/binary-amd64/Packages' in Release file (Wrong sources.list entry or malformed file)

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
Fetched 10.1 MB in 17s (565 kB/s)
ERROR: Service 'php' failed to build: The command '/bin/sh -c apt-get update -y' returned a non-zero code: 100
```

You can find the original php:5.6.32-apache `Dockerfile` here:
https://github.com/docker-library/php/blob/ec6b6e60b42c283d48775596f722f5250c1f5ca5/5.6/jessie/apache/Dockerfile

Duplicate. Please find solution at:
Build Error. Failed to fetch [Build Error. Failed to fetch http://deb.debian.org/debian/dists/jessie-updates/main/binary-amd64/Packages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52939411/build-error-failed-to-fetch-http-deb-debian-org-debian-dists-jessie-updates-m)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Build Error. Failed to fetch http://deb.debian.org/debian/dists/jessie-updates/main/binary-amd64/Packages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52939411/build-error-failed-to-fetch-http-deb-debian-org-debian-dists-jessie-updates-m)

Comment: @DavidMaze That's true. That solution resolved my problem. What should I do with my question now. Delete it?

Comment: @vivanov, actually I have the same problem much later with php:5.6.40-apache. In this case the proposed solution also worked, but with an adaptation. Apparently, it is built on debian 9 (stretch), as opposed to debian 8 (jessie), so the corresponding updates had to be made in the path of my patch. On the Docker Hub there are tags for both Debian distributions.